# Opencart 2.x access product only by link

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Is there anyway to remove a product from the catalog which the user sees but to leave it accessible only if you write the product's url?

Example:
 I have `opencart/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=43`

If I disable this product the user can see it on the site anymore. But I want users to be able to reach the product using the direct link still.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that by removing the following product from all Categories links.
hope i understood your question